# LM338 Voltage and Power Regulation

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator

I made a circuit using LM338 voltage regulator. Input voltage to circuit is 9V @5Amps using a power brick. I used 220 ohm resistor as R1 and R2 is 1K ohm potentiometer. When I assembled the circuit, I can see output variable voltage is coming out. I have set my output voltage 6v (maximum I want). But whenever I put load on it, voltage drops and servos attached to it misbehaves. I am not getting enough power out of  it.  My assumption is R1 resistor sets current and R2 sets voltage.  is it right?  Where is the problem.?
[image: Example circuit]

Comment: Is your power brick a regulated or unregulated wall wart? Did you add the capacitors recommended? And wired like this, R1 does not limit the current.

Comment: My power brick is regulated (Sony power adapter). I did not add capacitors as I was suggested capacitor are not necessary if voltages are low.

Comment: Input capacitor depends on the distance from the power brick to your LM338 (more than an inch). Output depends on load. But its easier to just add them. Also, if you are adding a large load like a motor, try adding a 100µF capacitor or so.

Comment: The LM338 can deliver 5 A **when cooled sufficiently**. If you draw 5 A at 6 V, the LM338 has to "burn-off" 9 V - 6 V = 3 V at 5 A = 15 Watt. You need a large heatsink for that. Also 3 V voltage drop is the **absolute minimum** the LM338 can manage.

Comment: *I did not add capacitors as I was suggested capacitor are not necessary if voltages are low.* Don't listen to such advise as it is **utter nonsense**. **Always** place the capacitors as recommended in the datasheet. The person who advised you not to place them because the voltages are low has no clue obviously.

Comment: "R1 sets current and R2 sets voltage": Wrong, R1 and R2 form a voltage divider: a fixed fraction of the output (R2/(R1+R2)*Vout) is compared to a fixed internal voltage reference (1.25V in your case), and the regulator has an internal control loop to cancel out the voltage difference. The series transistor (called "ballast") which serves as a variable resistor in the control loop is responsible for the minimum voltage drop for a given load current.

Comment: @FakeMoustache i got a massive heatsink and capacitors too.  Adding them  all won't  be a problem. HOWEVER ,  real  question  is power    why I am not getting enough  power?

Comment: How much does the voltage drop, and at what load? How much current are you actually pulling?

Comment: @Passerby voltage  drops nearly 2 V  and current  im getting is in miliamps... Whereas adapter provides 5 amps

Comment: Do a quick check on the voltage **input** when you are loading the output. At least that will eliminate the possibility that the supply isn't up to it.

Comment: The adapter only supplies the current demanded from it *up to* 5A.

Comment: @JImDearden done it various time.   It is accurate    also is sony brand adapter  i trust it.

Comment: Give it a sample load of 100 mA, a few leds with Appropriate resistors. See if it's stable or not like that

Comment: @JImDearden max current  it can supply  is 5.65 amp. Even my requirement is nearly 4 amps I dont mind having extra amps just in case i need more

Comment: @Passerby i will try that.  Whats best to  check maximum current  supplied at output port?

Comment: A stable test load, calibrated, temperature compensated. A power resistor is a simple method though. Just keep its wattage in mind. A 6V 5a load is 30 watts, so either multiple power resistors in parallel, or sufficient active cooling.

Comment: Always useful to have extra capacity but the point I was trying to make is that **the value of the current is determined by the load you place on its output**. Even very good brand power supplies (like Sony) can occassionally fail so its always good practice to check rather than assume.

Comment: @JImDearden you are right.  i used this adapter  because  it works fine with my ps2.   no problem  at all

Comment: The ps2 doesn't use a power brick though?

Comment: @Passerby they do use power brick...its very old ps2 ,  one with  big connectors  on its remote

Comment: @Passerby but anyway your suggestion  is to add capacitor  and change battery size right?

Answer (score 4):

Never assume.

Read the data sheet.
R2 and R1 set the voltage - and that ONLY in the diagram you posted.

There is an equation in the data sheet (on the same page you took the diagram from) that explains how to calculate the output voltage from R2 and R1.  The only tricky part is Iadj, which you have to find elsewhere in the datasheet.

The LM338 is a voltage regulator.  You can use an LM338 as a current regulator, but that is a different circuit from the one you gave.  If you need to regulate voltage and current, then you need to use the circuits given later in the datasheet.

You can only leave out the capacitors if the power conenctions are less than 6 inches (15cm.)  In any case, you are better off including them.  They don't cost much, and are **much** cheaper than replacing the hairs you ripped out while searching for a problem that could have been avoided by including them (the capacitors.)

The datasheet mentions the 6 inch limit for whether or not you need capacitors.  It doesn't say anything about the voltage playing into that decision, so whatever advice you got isn't backed by the datasheet.

As for the poor regulation:
You must cool the LM338 - it will need a good heatsink when operating at 5A.  If it gets hot, it will shut down.

The LM338 needs a good 3Volt difference between input and output voltage to work properly.  Your 9V input is too close to the required 6V output to work correctly and reliably.

Comment: Thanks for replying..  I checked all the circuits on datasheet but I couldn't  understand  them as my background  is not electronics. Howevrr there was a circuit for 12v battery charger.   Question is if R1 and R2 are not affecting  current then it should supply  input current  to output port. Isn't  correct?   But I am not getting enough  current near to input one

Comment: The last paragraph in my answer is important:  You need a higher voltage on the input in order to get 6 Volts on the output.  You have 9V going in and expect 6V going out, but the LM338 "loses" 3Volts in the regulator.  It can't regulate the 6V properly.  Supply it with 10 or even better 12V and see how it behaves.

Comment: Also, add the larger output capacitor as Passerby suggested (100µF.)

Comment: i got 12 V  battery,  i will give a try with it.   quick question.   Does regulator  chnage output current or not?   When used as voltage  regulator.  Thanks

Comment: i got 100uf and 470 uf capacitor I will add them as well.

Comment: The LM338 should not regulate the current in the circuit you posted.  It will shutdown or otherwise do things you don't expect if it gets too hot.

Comment: i can assure you that it is not getting hot at all.

Comment: Sure but that is because no current is flowing. When the 4 or 5 Amps are flowing, it **will** get hot.

Comment: @FakeMoustache and How do I solve  this?

Comment: The whole objective is to get 6V at minimum  3 amps

Comment: Maybe your servos pull a lot more than 3 A when they start, this causing the LM338 to shut down. Do you have 3 - 10 ohm power resistor or a (car) lightbulb. It does not matter if it is for 12 V. Then use that resistor or lightbulb as a load. Does that work ? Do you then get 6 V from the output ?

Comment: @FakeMoustache i will return to you  guys very soon once I have performed all these tests.. Thanks

Comment: I think you are asking a bit too much from that LM338. A Switching converter might be a better idea. Get a module like this one: http://www.ebay.nl/itm/DC-DC-5V-36V-to-3-3V-6v-12V-24V-5A-Buck-Step-Down-Voltage-Regulator-Module-Car-/361427218158?hash=item5426bdaeee:g:4fIAAOSw5VFWOdwr  Switching converters are much more power efficient so no large heatsink needed.

Comment: @FakeMoustache:  The LM338 is rated to supply 5A when properly heatsinked, and can handle transients up to 12A.  It ought to be able to provide 3A easily enough.

Comment: Sure but not if the input voltage is very close to the bare minimum.